# Auto- or code completion for PyCharm on Mac

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm

I need help with enabling auto-complete giving suggestions when I write code. I recently reinstalled PyCharm and I remember that the IDE giving me suggestions when I was writing, example:
I write "pr" and a suggestion list pops up with "print(), ...".

Couldn't find if this is a recent issue for Mac users but I tried comparing with a friend (Windows-user) and she had no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PyCharm 2019.2**:

Open up preferences (`⌘` + `,` or `PyCharm > Preferences`), navigate to `Editor > General > Code Completion` and check `Show suggestions as you type` checkbox. This will enable code completion suggestions when you type.

Alternatively, you can double tap `Shift` key, type in `code completion` and explore the options there.

Comment: Noticed that someone had enabled PowerSafe mode so it didn't work. Thanks!